# Java Sort particular index

Tags: java, sorting

I have a model

```
Hotel
  name
  bookings
  reviews
```

I have a strange sorting requirement and wanted to check with you if there is a better way
I need to sort list of books based on bookings and just the third item in the list with max number of reviews

What I have done so far and it works

- Created a default comparator on bookings to sort the list
- If the list is less than 3 do nothing
- If the list is greater than or equal to 3 split list in two 0 to 2 and 3 to end of list
- Create a new list and add first sublist to it.
- Find the max recommended item from second sublist (3 to end of list) and add it to the newly created list and remove from the second sublist
- Finally add the 2nd sublist which does not have max recommended but is sorted by number of bookings

Is there any performant efficient way of doing this?

Edit: Sorry here is the current code which works fine
public class HotelSort {

```
        public static void main(String args[]){
            List<Hotel> hotels = new ArrayList<>();
            hotels.add(new Hotel("A", 2, 50));
            hotels.add(new Hotel("B", 4, 30));
            hotels.add(new Hotel("C", 1, 60));
            hotels.add(new Hotel("D", 8, 10));
            hotels.sort(Comparator.comparing(Hotel::getNumberOfBookings).reversed());
    
            if(hotels.size() < 3){
                System.out.println(hotels);
            } else {
                var customSortedList = new ArrayList<>(hotels.subList(0, 2));
                var secondList = new ArrayList<>(hotels.subList(2, hotels.size()));
                var mostReviewedHotel = secondList.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Hotel::getNumberOfReviews)).orElseThrow();
                secondList.remove(mostReviewedHotel);
                customSortedList.add(mostReviewedHotel);
                customSortedList.addAll(secondList);
                System.out.println(customSortedList);
            }
        }
    }
```

The output in this case is which is correct but just wanted to see if there is a better performant way

```
Hotel{name='C', numberOfReviews=1, numberOfBookings=60},
 Hotel{name='A', numberOfReviews=2, numberOfBookings=50}, 
Hotel{name='D', numberOfReviews=8, numberOfBookings=10}, 
Hotel{name='B', numberOfReviews=4, numberOfBookings=30}
```

Comment: In addition to your literal description of how you approach the problem, it would be helpful to see the actual code with a sample input and the expected output.

Comment: @Eritrean sorry please find the working code

Comment: You don't need to create a new list, you can just `list.remove(mostReviewed); list.set(2, mostReviewed)`. Not sure if it's "more performant", but I doubt performance really is a big issue here anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @daniu in the comments you can remove the most reviewed element and add it back at the desired index. You can simplify the logic of finding the most reviewed element after a certain index by using Collections.max and passing a sublist. Something like below should be equivalent:

```
List<Hotel> hotels = new ArrayList<>();
hotels.add(new Hotel("A", 2, 50));
hotels.add(new Hotel("B", 4, 30));
hotels.add(new Hotel("C", 1, 60));
hotels.add(new Hotel("D", 8, 10));
hotels.sort(Comparator.comparing(Hotel::getNumberOfBookings).reversed());

if(hotels.size() > 3){
    var mostReviewedHotel =
            Collections.max(hotels.subList(2, hotels.size()), Comparator.comparing(Hotel::getNumberOfReviews));
    hotels.remove(mostReviewedHotel);
    hotels.add(2, mostReviewedHotel);
}
hotels.forEach(System.out::println);
```